# app not available on the google market Galaxy S4

Tags: android, galaxy

my app not available on Samsung Galaxy S4

ANDROIDMENIFEST FILE

```
<!-- PERMISSIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Optional permission to serve location-based ads -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Optional permission to enable the user to make calls from ads -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>
```

As per my knowldege compatible-screens tag is the main cause.

am i right or what can be the resson.

thanks in advance

Comment: Answare is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500309/any-way-to-support-samsung-galaxy-s4-using-compatible-screen-sizes?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to support `xxhdpi` devices since the S4 has a 441dpi. I believe the `xxhdpi` bucket starts at 440dpi.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the Galaxy S4 falls under the `large` screen bucket, but then so will certain 7" tablets. You will have to decide if you want to support that size or not in order to be compatible with the S4's 5" screen.

Comment: but i dont want to show my app on the tablets so is there any way through which i can show my apps only on phone devices ?

Comment: AFAIK I don't think it will be possible. Do you happen to know if the Galaxy Note 2 is compatible/can download from Play store?

Comment: just checked app on the Note 2 and its available there.

Comment: Hmmm... now that's interesting since that has a larger screen than the S4... Do you know the densities of the two screens?

Comment: http://www.gadgetgestures.com/samsung-galaxy-s4-vs-sony-xperia-z-comparison-of-design-features-camera-price/8344728

Both giants have the same screen size of 5 inches, display resolution of 1080*1920 pixels and a pixel density of 441 ppi. S4 is protected by the 3rd generation Corning Gorilla Glass and the Xperia Z features scratch-resistant and shatter-proof glass.

Comment: I wonder if the Note 2 falls under `normal/xhdpi` and the S4 falls under `normal/xxhdpi`...?

Comment: Do you know if the Xperia can download your app?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29494/discussion-between-zahid-naqvi-and-troniczomb)