# Any way to support samsung galaxy s4 using compatible screen sizes

Tags: android

I've recently released an app but the ui really isn't ready for larger tablet screen so until I get this fixed I've filtered out certain devices with an xlarge screen size using compatible screen tags:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    /* All sizes up to large xhdpi */
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Unfortunately, declaring compatible screen sizes like this in the manifest excludes the S4. I can't find a way of specifying compatible screens and not excluding the S4.

Note, a very similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401339/app-not-available-on-the-google-market-galaxy-s4) but the accepted answer (which indicates that at 441dpi the S4 falls under the xxhdpi screen density bucket) does not help in this particular situation as xxhdpi is not a valid manifest attribute value for screen density.

**EDIT:**

Many thanks for CommonsWare's answer below. The correct bucket for the S4 is then:

```
<screen
    android:screenDensity="480"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `480` instead of `xxhdpi` in the `<screen>` element.

Comment: For me the S4 is still not supported with these screen settings, any idea why? 

<compatible-screens><screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480"/></compatible-screens>

Comment: I believe it S4 is screenSize="large"

Comment: @keaukraine That is not correct.. Using only the `small` and `medium` screensize (with the `480` support) works for Xperia Z, Galaxy S4 and HTC One.

Comment: where to put dimens file for xxhdpi??

Comment: @Seppl did this one got working for you ?, if yes what are the  changes you have done....

Comment: @RenjithKN In the end this was the working solution. The problem I had was that I uploaded the apk for testing as alpha release, and then the supported devices wasn't updated. As a normal apk release the devices were updated correctl and it worked

Comment: @CommonsWare Is the `xxhdpi` string still unsupported? I keep getting the  `String types not allowed` error. Also, are other `xxhdpi` screens (e.g. Nexus 5, HTC One) supported? Can you provide links where this is better documented?

Comment: @domenicop: "Is xxhdpi still unsupported?" -- I avoid `<compatible-screens>` like the plague, so I have not looked into this recently. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) advises you to continue using `480`, though. "Also, are other xxhdpi screens (e.g. Nexus 5, HTC One) supported?" -- `xxhdpi` is `xxhdpi`, regardless of who makes it. "Can you provide some link where this is better documented (if they exists)?" -- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html