# Android App is not compatible with Samsung galaxy S4

Tags: android, google-play

I am having an Android app in the Market with Multiple APK Support. Now it is not supporting Galaxy S4 with screen resolution 1080x1920 and density 441dp;i.e. the app is not showing in Galaxy S4. What might the reason??? Please help????

Filter used in manifest (for apk which is supporting Galaxy S3 (screen size 4.8"), Galaxy Nexus (screen size 4.65") with 720x1280 resolution): 
compatible-screens 
            screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        compatible-screens

Note: screen density of S3 is 306dp and Nexus is 316dp

Comment: Would love to hear the answer to this!

Comment: @LordT Have any of the solutions posted helped you solve your problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct bucket for the Samsung Galaxy S4 is as follows:

```
<screen
   android:screenDensity="480"
   android:screenSize="normal" />
```

Credit also given to CommonsWare [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500309/any-way-to-support-samsung-galaxy-s4-using-compatible-screen-sizes).

Comment: For me the S4 is still not supported with these screen settings, any idea why? <compatible-screens><screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/><screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480"/></compatible-screens>

Comment: @Seppl one other option is normal/xxhdpi. What does that produce?

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value 'xxhdpi') during the build, so I guess it's a problem with the used SDK level

Comment: @Seppl what is your min/targetSDK?

Comment: @Seppl "xxhdpi" is not supported as of yet from what I can tell. What was the problem again with the "480"?

Answer (score 3):

you need to support xxhdpi devices since the S4 has a 441dpi.
I believe the xxhdpi bucket starts at 440dpi.
This should work for you. Most of the apps have been changed to support this.
Galaxy S4 falls under the large screen bucket, but then so will certain 7" tablets. You will have to decide if you want to support that size or not in order to be compatible with the S4's 5" screen.

**EDIT**

One of the s4 application manifest suggests the following

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Try this

Comment: I believe that the S4 is in the normal bucket, not large.

Comment: http://www.gadgetgestures.com/samsung-galaxy-s4-vs-sony-xperia-z-comparison-of-design-features-camera-price/8344728  
Both s4 and xperia have the same screen size of 5 inches, display resolution of 1080*1920 pixels and a pixel density of 441 ppi.

Comment: 5 in display can be either normal or large, up to the manufacturer.

Comment: You are correct about the xxhdpi, but I am not so sure on the large bucket.

Comment: try supports-screens with android:largeScreens="true"

Comment: Also, currently "xxhdpi" is not a supported density bucket from what I can see.