# Samsung Galaxy S4 Screen Size

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app compatible with the galaxy S4.
I understand I need to add the screen density 480 in the manifest, but is it classed as normal or large screen as people are saying different things?

For example, if I ran the following code on a **galaxy S4**, what would size result in?

```
int size = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

size = 2 = Normal, 
size = 3 = Large
```

Comment: You should do nothing to make your app compatible with Galaxy SIV ;-)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603203/android-app-is-not-compatible-with-samsung-galaxy-s4/16857757#16857757

Answer (score 2):

In your development, you should do nothing specific for a galaxy SIV, everything will scale.

If you want to play with different resources, you can use the qualifiers in your folders:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

This page will learn you a lot of usefull tricks: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for the useful info, however I am still intrigued what the outcome of the code would be

Comment: @Dandroid It will come out to be normal. See my answer from the comment above.

Comment: @TronicZomB indeed I checked out the link you provided and it showed some confusion with regards to Normal or Large size. Have you ran the code or are you just guessing?

Comment: If the S4 falls under the normal size bucket then that code will return just that.

Comment: I asked the question to ensure there was no "if"

Comment: There is no 'if'. Just develop like usual and your app will be compatible. Take care of 600dp for small tablets and 720 for 10 inches and there is NOTHING to worry about for the SIV. There are more than 6000 Android devices out there, there is no code for specific devices