# Android App is not compatible with Samsung galaxy S4 mini

Tags: android, screen-resolution, screen-size, multiscreen

I have Samsung galaxy s4 mini and screen size is 540 x 960 pixels, 4.3 inches (~256 ppi pixel density).
My app work perfectly in all devices accept galaxy s4 mini, galaxy s4, galaxy s5.
I have visited this link an try it but it doesn't affect in device. Link is below
[Android App is not compatible with Samsung galaxy S4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603203/android-app-is-not-compatible-with-samsung-galaxy-s4)
Any solution exist then please suggest me.

My AndroidManifest.xml file Code:
`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="com.utils.Constant"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:killAfterRestore="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="Video"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Result"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Login"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.beaconrangingservice.BeaconRangingService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <activity
        android:name="Home"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Infopage"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="BeaconFoundPage"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!--
    <service android:name=".EstimoteService" />
    <service
        android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService"
        android:exported="false" />
    -->
    <service android:name=".BeaconService" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
</application>`
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by not work, secondly, I have a galaxy s4, and dont see any issue with it.

Comment: I mean in all devices its look perfect but in s4 mini all views positions are changed.

Comment: Can you post the logcat log.

Comment: You just have to tweak with what is not showing right. Android devices vary in sizes and versions. That is why Google has these posts about best practices in supporting different screen sizes. (http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)  (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: If the application is crashing then it will show the probable cause

Comment: Actually app is not crashing from any activity. I think its design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

540 x 960 devices access `drawable-hdpi` `values-hdpi` folders.

please update your hdpi folder and check.

or u shud create layout `res/layout-w540dp-h960dp/layout.xml`  for specific size device,

Answer (score 0):

And what about sdk version? try to add this into your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: I think some issue for posting whole code but i have added min and max versions.

Comment: so, maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500309/any-way-to-support-samsung-galaxy-s4-using-compatible-screen-sizes?lq=1

Comment: I have also tried this but doesn't work and xxhdpi is doesn't exist.

Comment: you should use 480 instead of 'xxhdpi' as Commonsware said.

Comment: I have used this but not affecting anything and 'xxhdpi' is not exists.