# Android: What is the correct manifest declaration to target only smartphones in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I want to upload an application, which should be available for smartphones only (app needs functionality to start calls, so I want to exclude tablets...)

I read Googles [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html). I found the [supported-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html), but the `android:largestWidthLimitDp` attribute is available in 'API13' and I'm starting with 'API10'.

There are newer devices (Xperia Z, Galaxy S4 and HTC One) which use `drawable-xxhdpi` graphics and have a screen-resolution which is like a tablet.

**Question:** Is this manifest-declaration right for targeting only smartphones including the new smartphones?

```
 <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- support for Xperia Z, Galaxy S4 and HTC One -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" /> 
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" /> 
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps that is the way to do it. It'll support small, medium, and large screens of all densities, but won't support the extra large (tablet) screens.

Comment: please note that `makes calls` and `phone` are 2 sets of objects, quite close, but not identical. Some non-phonish devices are capable of making calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your app needs the ability to start phone calls. Why not filter on the telephony feature?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: What happens if tablet has LTE or can do call like Asus Phonepad?

Comment: `app needs functionality to start calls`, which the SO has for some reason interpreted as `phone only`. I think any tablet that can make call should be able to use an app that needs to make call.

Comment: @pocmo: Thanks for that! Is it possible to ONLY use your recommendation and remove the 'compatible-screens' at all? (so, app is for every device which can make calls?!)

Answer (score 2):

According to the `<uses-feature>` http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html documentation, the simple fact of having the `CALL_PHONE` permission (which you have if you are making calls) implies the `android.hardware.telephony` requirement, which effectively filters out any non-telephony-capable device.

On the other hand, restricting on screen size/density may exclude non-existing devices, requiring that you update your app every now and then. I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

@pocmo is right but you also should add

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

to your manifest file. android:largeScreens="false" and xlargeScreens="false" will remove tablets 7" and 10" from the list

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this official link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) at **Declaring app is only for handsets**:

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

Try to add:

```
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
```

or

```
<screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
```

Comment: but this doesn't select any `xxhdpi`-devices, does it? check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500309/any-way-to-support-samsung-galaxy-s4-using-compatible-screen-sizes

Comment: @longilong try to add "<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />" or "<screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />" .