# Different screen size issues

Tags: android

In my app, so far I have used these layout folders

```
layout-ldpi
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-large-hdpi
layout-large-mdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi
layout-xxxhdpi
```

Still, I am getting complaints about UI in some phones like Samsung Gaxay Grand 2 (280 ppi, 5.25" , 720 x 1280 pixels).

It is impossible to test app in every devices. So what are the common hardware profiles that I should set in my AVD so that most of the phones are covered up??

Comment: Try out Genymotion instead of Android emulator.

Comment: i use genymotion mostly... it has very limited configuration devices.... AVD allows us to create our own hardware profile

Comment: have you tried weight and weightsum...?else follow this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few known issues in Samsung phones. See this questions:

1. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-device)
2. [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500309/any-way-to-support-samsung-galaxy-s4-using-compatible-screen-sizes)
3. [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483895/android-galaxy-s4-uses-values-large)

Comment: The accepted answer in link "one" is pretty good but cant give the bounty to him. So, giving it to you :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding few more drawable folder like

```
layout-xlarge-hdpi
layout-xlarge-xhdpi
```

We are using this for few devices and it works. Could not able to test it in galaxy grand 2.

Comment: This way, we need to add about 15 layout folders to cover maximum devices. This will be way too much worksome!!

Comment: Different devices have different permutation combinations so its better to have individual folders instead of grouping it like nodpi

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
layout-long
layout-notlong
```

instead of

```
layout-ldpi
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-large-hdpi
layout-large-mdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi
layout-xxxhdpi
```

Comment: not getting the desired result... still the same problem in many devices

Comment: Are you setting size of the components in xml? Or you're using wrap_content and match_parent.

Comment: size of components is mostly wrap_content and match_parent except at couple of places.... The major issue is text sizes

Comment: You must set the text size according to screen size. I suggest you to use any device and try to find a better size for the texts, then you have divide the screen size by the right text size, so you will have a number. After that, you are able to multiply the screen size by this number, so you will have the text size again. Doing it, you can set the text size according to each screen size and your problem is resolved.